# Erlang and wxWidgets - Possible Bug

Tags: macos, erlang, wxwidgets

I am on Mac OSX 10.7 however I believe this would also appear in 10.8+

Try running (within erlang)

```
wx:demo().
```

Which will produce the following output:

beam.smp[2733:f0b] CFURLCreateWithString was passed this invalid URL string: '/System/Library/CoreServices/CommonCocoaPanels.bundle' (a file system path instead of an URL string). The URL created will not work with most file URL functions. CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath or CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPathRelativeToBase should be used instead.

Now the demo runs just fine but why output this line then?

It speaks nothing of erlang and after some browsing around it seems as if this is a wxWidgets bug as people have the same issue in python and that it is Mac OSX centric due to the CommonCocoaPanels.bundle in the output.

Its really just an annoyance for now as everything runs just fine.  But it is more than likely a bug, no?

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my future reference, and that of others..

The following will work without displaying the above error message.

> ```
> P = wx:new(),
> F = wxFrame:new(P, 1, "main", [{size, {600,600}]),
>
> WindowOpts = [{size, {600,600}}, {style, ?wxSUNKEN_BORDER}],
> W = wxWindow:new(F, ?wxID_ANY, WindowOpts),
>
> wxFrame:connect(F, close_window, [{skip,true}]),
> wxWindow:connect(W, paint, [{skip, true}]),
> wxFrame:show(F),
> wxFrame:centre(F).
> ```

Strangely enough even with all my trial and error debugging, line by line, there is really no easy way to get to the bottom of it.  It turns out to be the inclusion of a:

> process_flag(trap_errors, true)

Will generate that error.  I am positive there is nothing crashing that would invoke the actions of the flag.

Deep error. Little consequence.

Lets hope they get it fixed along with the 3.0 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know wxErlang is currently broken on MacOS and maintainers promise to fix it after wxWidgets 3.0 release.

Comment: If you know the maintainers, please let them know that it would be much better to fix the problems they run into in wxWidgets itself *before* 3.0 release. Doing it after it risks to be significantly more complicated. So I'd like to strongly encourage trying to make wxErlang work with the (upcoming) 2.9.5.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `wxWidgets` are you using? I used `wxWidgets 2.8.12` under `Mac OS 10.6.8`, custom build for `Carbon` with `-arch i386`.

> In wxWidgets 2.8.x, Carbon is the recommended library because it is the
>        more stable.  Cocoa is incomplete in wxWidgets 2.8.x.  If you are interested 
>        in using Cocoa, you should start with wxWidgets 2.9.x where Cocoa is 
>        much more complete.

The framework itself looked somehow alien to Max OS (maybe because of Carbon), a small part of API was broken (this does not prevent programs to actually run - just small annoyances).

Comment: I decided to use the erlang-solutions version with wxWidgets bundled into it.  Trying to compile was a serious PITA, do note I am not new to this.  I believe that it is 2.8.12, no one has had this problem?  Could it be specific to OSX Lion 10.7?

Comment: As I know you could compile it to use `Carbon` in `OSX 10.7`. Why not then? `Cocoa` is still less stable in 2.8.12, developers said that. But if you can live with that message, again - why not.